# weak cluster point of a sequnece in $c_0(\Gamma)$ space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(x_n) \subset c_0(\Gamma)$ be a sequence in $c_0(\Gamma).$ If $(x_n)$ has a w-cluster point, then $(x_n)$ is $||{\cdot}||_{\infty}$-bounded.
Also If $z \in w-\operatorname{cl}((x_n)_n),$ then $z \in c_0(\cup \operatorname{supp}x_n).$
How can I prove this facts without using metrizability of $(w-\operatorname{cl}((x_n)_n),w)$ since im trying to prove that.

Answer (score 1):

The first fact is false. Fix nonzero $y\in c_0(\mathbb N)$ and let
$$
x_n=\begin{cases} ny,&\ n\ \text{ odd}\\[0.2cm] 0,&\ n\ \text{ even}\end{cases}
$$
Then $\|x_n\|=n\,\|y\|$ for $n$ odd, so the sequence is not bounded; but $0$ is a (norm!) cluster point, as $x_{2n}\to0$.

The second fact is true. Suppose that $z=\lim_k x_{n_k}$, in the weak sense, for a subnet $\{x_{n_k}\}$. Denote by $\{e_n\}$ the canonical basis. Then
$$
z(j)=\langle z,e_j\rangle=\lim_k\langle x_{n_k},e_j\rangle.
$$
If $\def\supp{\operatorname{supp}}$$j\in \Big(\bigcup_n\supp x_n\Big)^c$, then $0=x_{n_k}(j)=\langle x_{n_k},e_j\rangle$ and thus $z(j)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if in some particular case it was the case for $(x_n)_n$ to be norm bounded in $c_0(\Gamma),$ then combined with the fact you just proved that $w-\operatorname{cl}((x_n)_n)\subset c_0(\bigcup_n \operatorname{supp} x_n)$ which has a separable dual $\ell_1( \bigcup_n \operatorname{supp} x_n) \cong \ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ would follow that $(B_{c_0(\cup \operatorname{supp}x_n)},w)$ is metrizable and then so is  any bounded set in particular $w-\operatorname{cl}((x_n)_n).$ Is this correct.